# how to Detect Device camera behavior in game scene in unity 3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to detect camera behavior in game scene in Unity3D ?

I tried with both the camera but front camera is not working properly , please help.

Comment: Can you explain the problem you're having a little better? As it is, it is hard to understand what it is :/

Comment: still the same. what camera? what behavior? what does "not working properly" mean exactly?

Comment: i am saying about device camera .

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
for (int cameraIndex = 0; cameraIndex < WebCamTexture.devices.Length; cameraIndex++)
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        // We want the back camera
        if (WebCamTexture.devices[cameraIndex].isFrontFacing)
        {
            //Your code
        }
#else
        if (!WebCamTexture.devices[cameraIndex].isFrontFacing)
        {
            //Your code
        }
#endif
    }
```

check WebCamTexture.devices.Length if its not equal 0. If your using Android add: < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>. If your using PC check if your camera is turned on and you have updated camera DRIVERS!